# Is it possible to exclude source files (appear as 'Decompiled Class') in IntelliJ while debugging

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

Is it possible to exclude source files (appear as 'Decompiled Class') in IntelliJ while debugging.

I would like to exclude the lib files like EJBDescriptors etc while debugging so that I dont step into them.

Is it possible from IntelliJ debugger?

Answer (score 4):

Not a blanket solution to avoid any decompiled class, but it sounds like you know what classes you want to avoid so here is my suggestion.

You can configure IntelliJ to skip classes/packages when stepping through code in settings in Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Stepping:

[image: IntelliJ Settings]

Comment: They are all marked.. But still I see my debugger stepping into all source classes as well. But let me try explicitly adding the classes that I want to skip..

Comment: flawless answer!